# How do I create a transaction out of multiple Rails save methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, transactions, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have a model that looks like this

```
class CryptoIndexCurrency < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :crypto_currency
end
```

I have a service method where I want to populate this table with records, which I do like so

```
CryptoIndexCurrency.delete_all
currencies.each do |currency|
  cindex_currency = CryptoIndexCurrency.new({:crypto_currency => currency})
  cindex_currency.save
end
```

The problem is the above is not very transactional, in as far as if something happens after the first statement, the "delete_all" will have executed but nothing else will have.  What is the proper way to create a transaction here and equally as important, where do I place that code?  Would like to know the Rails convention here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do:

```
CryptoIndexCurrency.transaction do
  CryptoIndexCurrency.delete_all
  CryptoIndexCurrency.create(currencies.map{ |c| {crypto_currency: c} })
end
```

Comment: What file are you putting this in?

Comment: Wherever you're doing your transaction, you said "I have a service method... which I do like so".  It will roll back on error, including the deletes, nonetheless I do agree that you should ensure validity on the records you're gonna be creating, but you should do it basically as you create the currencies array in the first place, to prevent looping twice the array (one for validation, one for mapping).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Activerecord you can use the builtin transaction mechanism. Otherwise, one way would be to make sure you validate all your data and only save when everything is valid. Take a look at `validates_associate` and the like.

That said, if your process is inherently non validatable/nondeterministic (eg. you call external APIs to validate a payment) then the best is to ensure you have some cleaning methods that take care of your failure

If you have deterministic failures:

```
def new_currencies_valid?(currencies)
  currencies.each do 
    return false if not currency.valid?(:create)
  end
  true
end

if new_currencies_valid?(new_currencies)
  Currency.delete_all # See note
  new_currencies.each(&:save)
end
```

A sidenote : unless you really understand what you are doing, I suggest calling `destroy_all` which runs callbacks on deletion (such as deleting `dependent: :destroy`) associations

Comment: Two things -- what file are you placing this code in and are tehse two lines -- "Currency.delete_all" and "new_currencies.each(&:save)" really run as an atomic unit?

Comment: I don't know about your business logic so I can't tell you where to put the files, but in a service object I guess. `new_currencies.each(&:save)` doesn't guarantee atomicity. What you're trying to do is not clear, what behavior are you expecting from a "transaction". Usually transactions are used to create a single (or a group of related) models, but was not designed for mass seeding. What should happen if there is an error midway ?. The `save` method will run all callbacks on the model but if you have none maybe you can hit lower-level drivers for your database.